# Is it better for SEO to repeat keywords already used inside of longer keyword phrases?

Tags: seo, keywords

Is it better for SEO to repeat keywords already used inside of longer keyword phrases, or just use the longer keyword phrase?

For example:

```
fleet management
fleet managemnt software
fleet management software in pune
fleet management software in india
```

The first two are already contained in the last two keyword phrases, so is it necessary to repeat these, or just use the last two longer keyword phrases.

Comment: Can you tell us where you plan on using these?

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you mean? For example, are you talking about headers, content, title tag, etc.? SEOs push the notion of keywords, however, that is not how search works for the major search engines especially Google. I can link to some answers that can provide some background for you if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google, SEO Doesn't depend Upon the Meta tags Keyword. And Google bots will never have a look at it.

But many SEO experts suggest using the Meta Keyword tag.

And To The answer of Your question, you can use the keywords any no of times as long as they are a different phrase.

But there's a word limit on keywords.

And also make a practice to use keywords in Content and Heading Tags.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about the keywords meta tag.